# Trigger on one DB2 database and insert into another DB2 database

Tags: database, db2

I have two databases db1 (Table1) and db2 (Table2). I have created a trigger on db1 Table Tabl1 insertion. I want to add that data in Table2 of db2. I come to know that it is possible in MySQL but I want to do same thing in DB2. can we achieve this in db2. any response will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. if you call insert/update/delete statement on nickname within trigger body

   A nickname cannot be an update target in a trigger.

   You can include SELECT statements on nicknames in the trigger body.

   You cannot include INSERT,  UPDATE, or DELETE statements on nicknames in the trigger body.

   http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.ii.doc/admin/tfpwrk01.htm
2. if you call insert/update/delete statement within storedprocedure and call that store procedure from trigger body.

   you will encounter error SQL20136N with SQLSTATE = 55047 and This will happen if you try to access a nickname within a nested path like the following:

   - table TAB1 on local database server
   - nickname NICK1 referencing some table on remote federated
     server
   - local stored procedure STP1 which will access NICK1
   - after insert trigger on TAB1 which will call stored
     procedure STP1

   After trigger on TAB1 got fired DB2 will start execution of
   stored procedure STP1. As soon as this stored procedure trys to
   access nickname NICK1 you will get error SQL20136N.

   In IBM DB2 LUW you have only read access to federated objects within trigger body.

   Inserts, Update and Delete requests will continue to fail as
   they could cause read/write conflicts in certain situations

   http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1JR24656

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate that by used Federation. You fererate a remote table as it were local to the database.

Comment: No, at least in DB2 LUW you cannot, because referencing nicknames in DML inside triggers is not allowed: ["A searched update, searched delete, insert, or merge operation on nicknames inside compound SQL is not supported."](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000931.html)

Comment: used federation but still can not update the nickname within trigger.

Comment: What about a trigger that call an external function that does the update in the other database?

Comment: tried but it gives me invokers privileges issue on package (created for remote data-source) while creating stored procedure while the user has GRANT privileges on the package.